# UDP Latency, Multiple Endpoints unicast

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I need to send the same datagram to many endpoints using UDP and the network does not support multicast, ONLY unicast.
To test I created a list of endpoinst (fake IPs in the supported address range) and one valid machine returning echo at the end of the list.
The goal is to measure end to end latency.
Using WireShark I see that the UDP messages are serialized very fast on the sender, but it takes long to receive the message.

Are Windows UDP sockests combined together and sent over the NIC after some time or condition occurs? How do I flush each datagram?

I see NoDelay and LingerOptions don’t apply for UDP, but is looks like it is lingering before sending.

Pseudo code:

- Generate List (5000 endpoints)
- Add Echo device at the end of the list
- Foreach (var ep in endpointList) {SendDataRetries(ep, payload);}

  ```
  public void SendDataRetries(string downlink, IPEndPoint ep, int retries)
  {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(downlink))
          return;


      Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(downlink + "\r\n");

      for (int x = 0; x < retries; x++)
      {
          try
          {

              using (Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
              {
                  server.DontFragment = true;                        
                  server.SendTo(sendBytes, ep);
                  server.Close(); //is this really needed to flush the write?
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("\n\nException\ndownlink:{0}\nep:{1}\nex:{2}", downlink, ep, ex));
              x--;
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: What do you mean that it "takes long to receive the message"?  How are you determining that?  And "how long" are we talking about ?

Comment: Also, you might speed things up by re-using the same socket for all endpoints. And preferably you bind your socket to a local port or port 0 to let the OS choose a port.

Comment: too long is 10-20 seconds. I determine that because I get the Echo back on the server. What I don't understand is that I see the Echo request on wireshark in milliseconds, but then it takes 10-20 seconds for the Echo response. If I only add 20-100 IP address to the list, the message returns right away. I want to understand if Windows combines the traffic out (Linger). The only reason I am not reusing the socket is because I believe it is not flushing the SendTo, but I don't understand what happens under the covers.

Comment: 10-20 seconds goes beyond any of the suggestions I just made above. You likely have an issue on your receiving side code.  Maybe you can post that code and the problem will be apparent.